# is there a corresponding /var/log/boot.log for shutdown?

Tags: linux, logs, shutdown

with `verbose` grub instead of `quiet`, you observe this screen for example upon boot and shutdown

[image]

There is `/var/log/boot.log` that has what was displayed on the screen from boot.

Is there a corresponding file that has what was displayed on the screen for shutdown, showing what items failed?

Comment: After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash /shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the `-b -1` option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`. For more `journalctl` help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username).  If you don't have `journalctl`, look in `/var/log/messages`